# error ansible when use docker role

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm using ansible on ubultu 16.04
i have a role to install docker,
this is the role :

```
    - name: Install Docker and role dependencies
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: "present"
    install_recommends: False
  with_items:
    - "apt-transport-https"
    - "ca-certificates"
    - "software-properties-common"
    - "cron"

- name: Get upstream APT GPG key
  apt_key:
    id: "{{ docker_apt_key }}"
    keyserver: "{{ ansible_local.core.keyserver
                   if (ansible_local|d() and ansible_local.core|d() and
                       ansible_local.core.keyserver)
                   else 'hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net' }}"
    state: "present"

- name: Configure upstream APT repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: "{{ docker_repository }}"
    state: "present"
    update_cache: True

- name: Install Docker
  apt:
    name: "docker-{{ docker_edition }}={{ docker_apt_package_name }}"
    state: "present"
    update_cache: True
    install_recommends: False
    cache_valid_time: "{{ docker_apt_cache_time }}"
```

when i execute the playbook,
i have this error on step "Get upstream APT GPG key"

```
TASK [nickjj.docker : Install Docker and role dependencies] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'apt-transport-https', u'ca-certificates', u'software-properties-common', u'cron'])

TASK [nickjj.docker : Get upstream APT GPG key] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable gpg in paths: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/skaouech/work/ansible/plays.retry
```

Any Advise please
thks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your target host doesn't have the `gpg` binary, according to the error you posted:

> Failed to find required executable gpg...

You'll probably need to install `gnupg`, which could be achieved with the ansible `apt` module.